# Running Visual C++ 6.0 under Windows XP - Updates and Requirements?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-6

Okay, so I have a legacy Codebase and an old Visual C++ 6.0 Standard Installation CD. I want to install that on my Windows XP SP3 System.

Is there anything I would need to avoid or to download besides SP6?

Are executables created with VC6 compatible on Vista and Windows 7? (I know that there is no 64-Bit compiler, and that's fine)

(I know that vc6 is old, unsupported and [somewhat crappy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625990/), but my C++ skills are barely good enough to compile, make 2 or 3 small changes and re-compile, but not good enough to make sure it compiles in VS2008)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fine.  Install SP6 and that should be it.  You might need other dependencies; the platform SDK, if you need it, will require hunting for an older version than what's currently available.

Comment: Looks good. It's able to compile my code and the application runs as expected so far.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it should run fine provided you install VC++ runtime. I think you should install VC6 runtime to be sure, not the recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

For latecomers who don't know where to get this "SP6" we're talking about, it's at:

- ["Visual Studio 6.0 service packs, what, where, why"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194022)
- ["Product Updates for Visual C++ 6.0"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/aa336441.aspx)
- ["Service Pack 6 for Visual Basic 6.0, Visual C++ 6.0 with Visual Source Safe 6.0d"](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=A8494EDB-2E89-4676-A16A-5C5477CB9713&displaylang=en)